# Compilation silently fails, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I was working on my flash project, which compiled the whole time just fine.
Then I did some changes, then, when testing the project, the project compiles,
the flash player comes up, showing the first frame, but no code executes. 
No single trace output. Nothing. No Errors, No Warnings, very strange!!!

Can anybody help me???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have stumbled over a BUG in the FlashIDE/Flex Compiler.

Try this snippet and wonder:

```
// ------ Put in first frame of a fresh flash file 

trace ("why won't i execute");

var dummy=function(a:int){

    a:int = 0;

}
```

Instead of catching your coding mistake:

`a:int = 0;` should eihter be `var a:int = 0;` or `a=0;`

the compiler chokes, and dies,  without even having the time to let you know.

**Beware!**

This mistake can be deeply hidden in some, over many intermediate classes imported, class.

So, to answer your question, look at the things you have changed, you might have changed a local var to be given as a function argument, took away the local `var` but forgot to remove the `:type` part as well.